# Need to Solve a Formula Having 2 Variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a percentage of 50%. I need to get to 50% with 2 variables. The two numbers I have are 54 and 112 which is 48.21%. I need to figure out what the first number needs to be to get to 50%, but the catch is that both numbers increase at the same time.  The scenario is I need to be at 50% of outbound calls for the month. My current outbound calls are 54, and my total calls are 112. I need to be at 50% outbound. So if I log 1 outbound, that will increase to 55 but my total will increase to 113. I know the answer is 4 calls needed (58 outbound and 116 total), but how do I figure that out using the numbers I have?

Comment: That should be 58 outbound and 116 total in your last sentence, right?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way forward.

If you have $54$ outbound calls out of $112$ and need to get the ratio up to $0.5 = 50\%$, you'll solve this equation:

$$\frac{54 + x}{112 + x} = 0.5.$$

In other words, some number of calls $x$, added to the calls you've already made, will bring the ratio up to $0.5$.

Multiply both sides by $(112 + x)$ and solve for $x$.

Can you take it from here?  (You should get $x=4$ as your answer.)